# How to map a number in some ranges

Tags: javascript, normalize

I have a range of values like, for example, `[0, 100] = [minValue, maxValue]` and the number of bands, for example `BANDS_NUMBER = 5`.
So I can obtain these bands:

```
[0 - 20]
[21 - 40]
[41 - 60]
[61 - 80]
[81 - 100]
```

Then I want to associate a **scale value** at each range:

```
i: 0   -->  [0 - 20]   -->  0.2
i: 1   -->  [21 - 40]  -->  0.4
i: 2   -->  [41 - 60]  -->  0.6
i: 3   -->  [61 - 80]  -->  0.8
i: 4   -->  [81 - 100] -->  1
```

This value is computed in this way: `(i + 1) / BANDS_NUMBER` where `i` is the index of a hypothetical loop.

Then I have an input `n` whose value is in range `[minValue, maxValue] = [0, 100]`.

What I want is the *scale value* related to this number.
So, for example, if:

```
n = 0  --> scaleValue = 0.2 
n = 10 --> scaleValue = 0.2 
n = 20 --> scaleValue = 0.2 
n = 35 --> scaleValue = 0.4
n = 68 --> scaleValue = 0.8 
n = 99 --> scaleValue = 1
...
```

How can I create a function like that? I imagine a function like that:

```
function map(n, minValue, maxValue, bandsNumber) {
  const scaleValue = ...
  return scaleValue
}
```

All the values here are examples, I want that all works with any other values.

I don't know how to do to that. I need some help...

Comment: The first set contains 21 items while the others have 19, is it normal?

Comment: @KévinBibollet First set contains 21, second to last sets contain 20, not 19.

Comment: @KévinBibollet Ye, it's not a problem if sets don't contains the same number of elements

Comment: It might me not a problem that the sets don't contain the same number of elements, but then you have to indicate how you want to distribute the range. In your example, you decide that the one additional element belongs to the first set. Is that always the case? What if there are 2 or more additional elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nina Scholz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56538402/783743) is wrong. Her normalize function returns `0.4` instead of `0.2` for the value `20`:

```js
function normalize(min, max, bands, n) {
    return n === max
        ? 1
        : Math.floor(1 + ((n - min) / (max - min)) * bands) / bands;
}

console.log(normalize(0, 100, 5, 20)); // expected 0.2, actual 0.4
```

Because `20` is in the first band, it should have the value `0.2`:

```js
i: 0   -->  [0  - 20]  -->  0.2
i: 1   -->  [21 - 40]  -->  0.4
i: 2   -->  [41 - 60]  -->  0.6
i: 3   -->  [61 - 80]  -->  0.8
i: 4   -->  [81 - 100] -->  1
```

The correct answer is:

```js
const index = (min, max, bands, n) =>
    Math.floor(bands * (n - min) / (max - min + 1));

const band = n => index(0, 100, 5, n);

console.log(band(0),  band(20));  // 0 0
console.log(band(21), band(40));  // 1 1
console.log(band(41), band(60));  // 2 2
console.log(band(61), band(80));  // 3 3
console.log(band(81), band(100)); // 4 4
```

As you can see, the edge cases are handled correctly. How did we get to this answer?

1. First, we find the length of the range which is `max - min + 1`. The `+ 1` is important because there are 101 elements in the range `[0 - 100]` inclusive.
2. Next, we get the index of the number `n` in the given range (i.e. `n - min`).
3. Then, we divide the index of `n` by the number of elements in the range to get a value in the range `[0 - 1)`. Note that `1` is not in the range.
4. Finally, we multiply this value by the number of bands and discard the fractional part. The result is our index.

Note that if the length of the range is not divisible by the number of bands then the first `x` bands will have one additional element, where `x` is the remainder of dividing the length of the range by the number of bands.

Finally, we can get the value you want by incrementing the resulting index and then dividing it by the number of bands:

```js
const index = (min, max, bands, n) =>
    Math.floor(bands * (n - min) / (max - min + 1));

const value = (min, max, bands, n) =>
    (index(min, max, bands, n) + 1) / bands;

const result = n => value(0, 100, 5, n);

console.log(result(0),  result(20));  // 0.2 0.2
console.log(result(21), result(40));  // 0.4 0.4
console.log(result(41), result(60));  // 0.6 0.6
console.log(result(61), result(80));  // 0.8 0.8
console.log(result(81), result(100)); // 1 1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a formula, which take the range and the slot and returns a normalized value.

Because of the range, which is a bit too long (the last value is included in the interval), you need a check for the last value and prevent getting the next value, outside of the wanted interval.

```js
function normalize(min, max, bands, n) {
    return n === max
        ? 1
        : Math.floor(1 + ((n - min) / (max - min)) * bands) / bands;
}

// 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.8 1 1
console.log(...[0, 10, 20, 35, 68, 99, 100].map(normalize.bind(null, 0, 100, 5)));
```

Comment: Thanks but what I want is a bit different. I prefer your function became like that `function normalize(minValue, maxValue, bandsNumber, n) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a native `Array.map` function to map each value.

Something like this:

```js
const vals = [
  [0, 20],
  [21, 40],
  [41, 60],
  [61, 80],
  [81, 100],
];

const BANDS_NUMBER = 5;

const result = vals.map((range, index) => (index + 1) / BANDS_NUMBER);

console.log(result);
```