# Use scales to remap a number

Tags: javascript

I have a domain of numbers, for example `domain = [100, 200]` and a number of bands in which to divide the range, for example `bands = 5`.
I know that each band corresponds to a value:

```
band #1 --> v = 0.2
band #2 --> v = 0.4
band #3 --> v = 0.6
band #4 --> v = 0.8
band #5 --> v = 1.0
```

These values are fixed (hard coded): if bands became `bands = 6` then is the developer that choose what is the value of `band #6`.

I want to divide the domain into bands whose size varies according to the scale used. 
For example I might want to use either the linear or the logarithmic or the pow scale.

Then I want a function that in input takes a number `x ∈ domain` and must return the value `v` associated with the band to which the inout number belongs.

[Here a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538235/how-to-map-a-number-in-some-ranges?noredirect=1#comment99659132_56538235), but now I want to use different scales (for example I can use `d3 scales`) but I don't know how..

Here a piece of code:

```
function getLinearScaledValue(x, min, max, bands) {
  const range = max - min
  if (x === max) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return Math.floor(1 + ((x - min) / range) * bands) / bands
  }
}
```

where `min` and `max` are the min and max value of the domain.

I think sleepwalking's examples was good so I put them here:

if bands = 5:

```
band #1 --> v = 0.2
band #2 --> v = 0.4
band #3 --> v = 0.6
band #4 --> v = 0.8
band #5 --> v = 1.0
```

(1) if scale is linear and domain = [0, 100] --> bands are:

```
band #1 --> v = 0.2 --> [0, 20]
band #2 --> v = 0.4 --> [21, 40]
band #3 --> v = 0.6 --> [41, 60]
band #4 --> v = 0.8 --> [61, 80]
band #5 --> v = 1.0 --> [81, 100]
```

for example:

```
if x = 0  --> v = 0.2
if x = 10 --> v = 0.2
if x = 21 --> v = 0.4
if x = 98 --> v = 1.0
```

(2) if scale is linear and domain = [100, 200] --> bands are:

```
band #1 --> v = 0.2 --> [100, 120]
band #2 --> v = 0.4 --> [121, 140]
band #3 --> v = 0.6 --> [141, 160]
band #4 --> v = 0.8 --> [161, 180]
band #5 --> v = 1.0 --> [181, 200]
```

for example:

```
if x = 100 --> v = 0.2
if x = 110 --> v = 0.2
if x = 121 --> v = 0.4
if x = 198 --> v = 1.0
```

(3) if scale is logarithmic and domain = [0, 100] --> bands are:

```
band #1 --> v = 0.2 --> [?, ?]
band #2 --> v = 0.4 --> [?, ?]
band #3 --> v = 0.6 --> [?, ?]
band #4 --> v = 0.8 --> [?, ?]
band #5 --> v = 1.0 --> [?, ?]
```

for example:

```
if x = 0  --> v = ?
if x = 10 --> v = ?
if x = 21 --> v = ?
if x = 98 --> v = ?
```

Comment: please add some examples with different domains.

Comment: @NinaScholz I added some examples

Comment: @sleepwalking I think OP should add the examples. Are you 100% sure you understand exactly what OP is asking for ?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a quantization algorithm.

Comment: @Caramiriel Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599249/783743) I showed the correct function to calcuate the band index of a number within a range:

```js
const index = (min, max, bands, n) =>
    Math.floor(bands * (n - min) / (max - min + 1));

const band = n => index(0, 100, 5, n);

console.log(band(0),  band(20));  // 0 0
console.log(band(21), band(40));  // 1 1
console.log(band(41), band(60));  // 2 2
console.log(band(61), band(80));  // 3 3
console.log(band(81), band(100)); // 4 4
```

The above function uses a linear scale. However, it's easy to generalize it to use another scale:

```js
const index = (scale, min, max, bands, n) =>
    Math.floor(bands * scale(n - min) / scale(max - min + 1));

const log = x => Math.log(x + 1);

const logBand = n => index(log, 0, 100, 5, n);

console.log(logBand(0),  logBand(1));   // 0 0
console.log(logBand(2),  logBand(5));   // 1 1
console.log(logBand(6),  logBand(15));  // 2 2
console.log(logBand(16), logBand(39));  // 3 3
console.log(logBand(40), logBand(100)); // 4 4
```

Here we used the logarithmic scale. Note that we incremented the index before calculating its logarithm because the logarithm of zero is undefined, although JavaScript happily returns the limit of the natural logarithm of `x` as `x` tends to zero (i.e. `-Infinity`). However, `-Infinity` is not a valid index.

Anyway, our ranges are as follows:

```js
i: 0   -->  [0  - 1]   -->  0.2
i: 1   -->  [2  - 5]   -->  0.4
i: 2   -->  [6  - 15]  -->  0.6
i: 3   -->  [16 - 39]  -->  0.8
i: 4   -->  [40 - 100] -->  1
```

Note that although our scale is logarithmic yet our ranges grow exponentially. This makes sense because when we scale our range logarithmically we're squishing numbers together. Hence, when we divide our squished range into bands, the number of elements in each band grows exponentially. It can be best explained by the following graph:

[image: Logarithmic Scale]

One the x-axis we have our linear scale with values from `1` to `101`. On the y-axis we have our logarithmic scale with values from `log(1)` to `log(101)` (denoted as 5/5 for educational purposes). As you can see, we're dividing our logarithmic range into even sized bands. However, on our linear scale those bands become exponentially bigger.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need conventions. You need to ask yourself the right questions.

What does logarithmic mean? The logarithm function has two inputs, a base and a value. The output is the power to which you raise the base in order to get the number. Let's suppose that the base is 2, and that the domain is 0–200. In this case you calculate `log(2, 200)`, which is approximately `7.64`. This means that we have the limits, `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]`. If we exclude 1 (i.e. 2<sup>0</sup>), then we have 6 borders, which means we have 7 regions.

What happens if the domain is 200–400? In this case you would have only two regions, which doesn't make sense. In contrast with linear scaling, logarithmic scaling will yield different results for different domains even if their size is the same.

I think it makes sense to consider domains to be vectorial, i.e. it's irrelevant whether the domain is from 0–200 or from 200–400. The only constraints are that the domain is positive and 200 long. So, the domain 200–400 would be divided similarly to the domain 0–200, the only difference being the values. For the division itself we use the indices.

If we accept this convention, then the problem is greatly simplified. The domain 200–400 has a length of 201. Hence, instead of `[1, 2, 4, 8,  16, 32, 64, 128]` we have `[201, 202, 204, 208, 216, 232, 264, 328]`.

Now the logarithmic scale look like the linear scale. The number of borders in the linear scale is equal to the base of the logarithm. Hence, in the case of a logarithmic scale, we would have this:

```
function getBaseLog(x, y) {
  return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}

function getLogarithmicScaledValue(x, min, max, base) {
    return parseInt(getBaseLog(base, x - min));
}
```

See the [logarithmic base conversion](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/change-of-base-formula-for-logarithms/a/logarithm-change-of-base-rule-intro).

An obvious use-case of logarithmic scaling is that it plays well with heap data structures.

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. The OP wants to scale a range (e.g. using a logarithmic scale) and then divide the scaled range into a given number of bands. The number of bands can be arbitrary (i.e. it's independent of the scaling function and the size of the domain). Also, speaking of the size of the domain, the range 0–200 has 201 elements.

Comment: @AaditMShah thanks for the comment, I have edited my answer where I have mistakenly said that the domain 200-400 has a length of 200. It is of course 201. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @beth is Aadit M Shah right? Did I misunderstand your question?